Is there a way to comment out a block of code in React that already has comments in it?
I want to comment out a giant block of code that already has react comments in it, but doing so will not work.
E.g.
{/*
                {/* my comment */}
                <div className="flex flex-col px-4 space-y-1 border-b pb-2 mt-2">
*/}

This fails

What's preventing you from simply deleting the code? A version control system (eg Git) can help you maintain history

What is causing you issues is the close comment indicator on the inner comment. React doesn't see comments inside of comments. If you remove the * / or even just the * from the line {/* my comment */} React will  move on to the next close comment indicator.

The problem is that there are a lot of these comments, and I want to quickly comment out different sections and put them back in

That's what I could figure out
{() => `/*{/* my comment */}
    <div className="flex flex-col px-4 space-y-1 border-b pb-2 mt-2"></div>
    */`}

